# Subtract record from previous record within same column in teradata

Tags: datetime, teradata, subtraction

Suppose there is column as shown below.

[image]

How to subtract record from previous record. for example the first record from second record and so on and then store in third column. As these are date values I want results in this format:
1d:1h:46m

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PRECEDING`:

```
select
<key>,
(<your column> - PreviousValue) DAY(4) TO MINUTE
from
(
select
<some sort of key>,
    <your column>,
    min(<your column>) over (partition by <whatever your grain is> ORDER BY <whatever> ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING) as PreviousValue
    from <your table>
    ...
    ) t1
```

If you don't need to partition by anything, just leave out the `partition by`